# Tracking Soundcloud plays using Facebook Pixel

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, soundcloud, conversion-tracking

This is my first post, I'm glad to join the community. I have very limited, practically no experience with coding, however I am working on something that requires me to jump into coding, so here I am.

My objective is to use the Facebook Advertising tracking pixel to track Soundcloud plays on my page and ultimately target people who have been listening to my tracks on Soundcloud.

Facebook usually allows you to track conversions from your own website, however it says that If you do not own the website where you are trying to track some information from, you should contact the website and ask them.
I have tried contacting Soundcloud but obviously received no response.

I was wondering wether there was a way to get around the issue that I do not own the website and therefore cannot copy and paste the Facebook pixel into Soundcloud's HTML.

I have done some research online, looking into forums, but there seems to be no discussion about this online, at least nothing that I could understand with my limited knowledge.

Here are a few links i checked out before posting here, unfortunately with little success.

http://www.unified.com/developers/earned-measurement/guides/conversion-soundcloud-plays/

http://www.unified.com/developers/earned-measurement/apis/conversions-js/

Thank you for your time,

Any help is appreciated.

Kindest regards,

Oliviero

Comment: No, you are not gonna be able to inject a tracking pixel into a website you don't own without their cooperation.

Comment: That's a shame. Not even with any sort of plug in? I find it bizarre Facebook and soundcloud are not collaborating on this.